# Regex C# - how to match methods and properties names of a class

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match methods name (with parameters) and properties name. I dont want to include accessors in match.
For example i got this kind of class:

```
public class test
{
    public static string NA = "n/a";

    public static DateTime DateParser(string dateToBeParsed)
    {
        DateTime returnValue = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParse(dateToBeParsed, GetCulture(), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal , out returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

For class name I'm using this kind of regex: **(?<=class\s)[^\s]**+ for methods im trying something like this: **[^\s]+(?=()** but this will select all that text that has **(**. For methods i need to select that line that has **(** and accessors like public,private and protected. How to do it without including this in final match ? I need only method name and parameters within parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Use this `Regex`

```
(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s)?[\s\w]*\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:(ref\s|/in\s|out\s)?\s*(?<parameterType>\w+)\s+(?<parameter>\w+)\s*,?\s*)+\)
```

and get groups named `methodName` and `parameterType` and `parameter`.

Your code can be like this:

```
var inputString0 = "public void test(string name, out int value)\r\nvoid test(string name, int value)";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString0, @"(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s)?[\s\w]*\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:(ref\s|/in\s|out\s)?\s*(?<parameterType>[\w\?\[\]]+)\s+(?<parameter>\w+)\s*,?\s*)+\)"))
{
    var methodName = match.Groups["methodName"].Value;
    var typeParameterPair = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var capture in match.Groups["parameterType"].Captures)
    {
        typeParameterPair.Add(match.Groups["parameterType"].Captures[i].Value, match.Groups["parameter"].Captures[i].Value);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but what about `void test(string name, int value)` and `public void test(string name, out int value)` - which are both valid declarations?

Comment: Two more: `void test(string name, int[] value)` and `void test(string name, params int[] value)`. I don't want to be a pain, I'm just trying to show my point: something that's ok now will fall apart for some case you didn't think of :)

Comment: ITS great :). How to select that text (in final match) without key words like public but only a property name and method name ?

Answer (score 3):

How about using reflection ?

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string assemblyName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), string.Format("temp{0}.dll", Guid.NewGuid()));
        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[]
        {
            "System.dll",
            "Microsoft.CSharp.dll",
        }, assemblyName);

        CompilerResults cr = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, File.ReadAllText("Program.cs"));

        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("volatile");
            Proxy p = (Proxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Proxy).FullName);
            p.ShowTypesStructure(assemblyName);
            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
            File.Delete(assemblyName);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void ShowTypesStructure(string assemblyName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
            MethodInfo[] mis = type.GetMethods();
            foreach (MethodInfo mi in mis)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + mi.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the class he's trying to parse is not part of the executing assembly, but compiling the code dynamically and using reflection could be a good idea...

Comment: Updating the answer to include dynamic compiling.

Comment: I couldn't try it out, but I like it :) +1 from me!

Comment: But, can i use it on .cs files ? I that code above, where is a place to add path to .cs file ? EDIT ok sorry you just updated your code. GREAT :). GUYS i got general question: from what i can build a class diagram - from dlls or .cs files ? I really dont know now.

Comment: If you're using Visual studio, you can add a new "Class Diagram" item and drag your class on it, code must compile. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx
If not, you can check external tools, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600802/tools-for-generating-uml-class-diagram-from-c-sharp-source-or-dll

Comment: How to add a new Class Diagram in Visual 2010 express edition ? I cant see that kind of option in "add new item" menu. Maybe its available for full version of visual studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be rather hard to do this with regular expressions.

You could try creating a proper parser instead. The [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) library is easy to use, and one of the examples is a C# parser.

If you want to use regular expressions, however, you can try using a tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), which will help you test and build your regular expression.

You should also write a lot of unit tests - it's rather easy to break something when you modify a regular expression.

Sorry for not providing a "concrete" help, of the kind "use this expression", but I think that if you want to avoid a parser it's really a lot of work :)

Comment: Thx for the tip but i need to do this automatic ;). I need to take that information from .cs file write it to txt/xml file. To be honest with accessors and keywords this task shouldnt be that hard. Or maybe you know easier way to do it ? To retrive from cs (class file) properties and methods names)

Comment: @born2fr4g: why isn't this automatic? :)
Check that library and the examples that come with it, it's really worth it and should not take very long. The risk with a Regex is that something that works in one case will not be generic enough to handle another valid case..

Comment: But i got 2.0 NET project, but Irony requires NET 4.0 and how to use it ? This lacks a documentation a bit ;)

Comment: Well... you should have said it's .net 2.0 stuff :P

Comment: Sorry about that but thank You for tip anyway :) - i will check this irony library. Do you have any links to examples or extended documentation ?

Comment: The source code of the library itself contains many useful examples.

Comment: Im usig RegExr: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is also good ;). Thanks again for the tip