# Does not match sentence that contains specified character

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to match properties in class. Example class:

```
public static string ComingSoonPage
{
   get { return "/blog-coming-soon.aspx"; }
}

public static string EncodeBase64(string dataToEncode)
{
   byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncode);
   string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
   return returnValue;
}
```

Im using this kind of regex:

```
(?:public|private|protected)([\s\w]*)\s+(\w+)[^(]
```

It matches not only properties but also methods which is wrong. So i want remove from matches sentences that contains **(**. So it select all but not methods (which contains **(** ). How can i achieve that.

Comment: Don't forget the `internal` access modifier

Comment: I'm confused because what you have should do what you describe...

Answer (score 2):

Try matching the `"{"` and the `"get {"` instead

```
(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+(\w+)\s*\{\s*get\s*\{
```

---

**UPDATE**

Match only the name of the property

```
(?<=(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+)\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\s*\{)
```

uses the general pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

---

**EDIT**

A property might have no modifier (public, private etc.) at all and the type might contain extra characters (e.g. for arrays `int[,]`. Therefore it would probably be better to test only for the syntax elements following the property name (and the name itself). Also a property could consist of only a setter and be abstract: `abstract int[,] Matrix { set; }`. I suggest retrieving the property names like this:

```
\w+(?=\s*\{\s*(get|set)\b)
```

where `\b` matches a word beginning or (in this case) a word end.

Comment: Yeah, its another way ;). But is there is a way that regex does not match sentence with specified character/word ? Below is my modification to your code:  **(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+(\w+)(?=\s*\{\s*get\s*\{)**. It does not include get in result :).

Comment: I often use `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` to match a position between a prefix and a suffix. To get only the name of the property you would use `(?<=(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+)\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\s*\{)`

Comment: `RegexOptions.Singleline` mode may help

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes  - your code for match only property name does not work ;). It matches nothing.

Comment: @born2fr4g 2 way checking may help..chk out my answer

Comment: @Anirudha that part for methods names still not working ;). Im going to use **Match.Groups** to write only properties names. Anyway - thank you for your help :).

Comment: @born2fr4g making groups is very complex..What method names are not working..I am not getting..I tried my code and its working perfectly!

Comment: @Anirudha Im using this http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to check regex code. I copied your regex code which is: **(?<=(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+)\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\s*\{)** as match code and my example class code (that i placed in question above) and there is no match ;). Nothing is matched.

Comment: @born2fr4g that's not my regex...check the answer given by me..the one above this answer!!

Comment: @born2fr4g: I tested the expression and it works for me. `string result = Regex.Match("public static string ComingSoonPage\r\n{\r\n get { return \"x\"; }\r\n}", @"(?<=(public|private|protected|internal)[\s\w]*\s+)\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\s*\{)").Value; Console.WriteLine(result); // ==> "ComingSoonPage"`. But keep in mind that types can have other characters `public int[] IntArray { get { return null; } }`

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for and this works perfectly! I deserve some treat though :)...

```
Regex r=new Regex(@"(public|private).*?(?=(public|private|$))",RegexOptions.Singleline);
Regex nr=new Regex(@"\(.*?\)\s+\{",RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(yourCodeFile))//extracts all methods and properties
{
if(!nr.IsMatch(m.Value))//shoots down methods
m.Value;//properties only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11914533/1495442), try using:

for **`Properties`**: *`type`* and *`name`*:

```
(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s|internal\s)\s*(?:readonly|static\s+)?(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<name>\w+)[\s\r\n]*{
```

for **`Fields`**: *`type`* and *`name`*:

```
(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s)\s*(?:readonly|static\s+)?(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<name>\w+);
```

for **`Methods`**: *`methodName`* and *`parameterType`* and *`parameter`*:

```
(?:public\s|private\s|protected\s|internal\s)?[\s\w]*\s+(?<methodName>\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:(ref\s|/in\s|out\s)?\s*(?<parameterType>\w+)\s+(?<parameter>\w+)\s*,?\s*)+\)
```

for c# code analysis try [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) or [The Roslyn Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx), see this sample:

- [C# and VB.NET Code Searcher - Using Roslyn](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416472/Csharp-and-VB-NET-Code-Searcher-Using-Roslyn) *codeproject*

Comment: Its almost good but its not working on fields; it matches nothing (empty match). And when im using your code for fields from that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11914533/931067 i match not only fields but also properties.